# Concatenated error messages for all JSON responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, api

I have a Rails app that has both HTML and JSON endpoints, and the JSON is being used by an iOS app. The iOS developer would like all error messages output to be changed from something like `{"errors":{"email":["has already been taken"],"password":["is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}}` to the form `{ "error" : "message"}`, but there doesn't seem to be a good place to do a single fix/formatting.

#### My feeling is there are 3 different steps here:

1. Modifying error responses for JSON responses only
2. Calling `.full_messages` on all errors
3. Standardizing keys so `errors` or other variations become simply `error`

#### My questions:

1. Is there a place to set the error format to `full_messages` for all JSON messages or does it need to be spliced into all error calls?
2. Is there a place to standardize keys for all errors?

   - I guess I could reopen `as_json` in `ActiveRecord::Base`, but there may be other errors not coming from AR...

#### Potential items

These are potential solutions that have been mentioned so far.

1. Presenters

   - This seems useful for aggregating information from multiple models but still requires that the new Class be called in each method.
   - I was hoping for a higher-level solution that caught output and reformatted it before passing it along without having to manually insert it throughout the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably late answer but if it helps add more perspective.

I use RABL as the json presentation layer and tried to use that to output json errors to ios.

Example code in RABL:

`object @submission`

child :errors do |e|
  e.full_messages.each do |message|
      node(:message){message}
   end
 end

Now, logging NSError *error object gives the following in UserInfo dictionary as expected: 
UserInfo=0xa166bc0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"submission":{"fixnums":[{"photo_file_size":{"message":"Photo file size must be in between 0 Bytes and 153600 Bytes"}}]}}

One can notice value of UserInfo dictionary does not return an ios dictionary friendly format. '=' are instead ':', arrays have '[' instead of '(' and ')'

Is a suggested solution to perhaps add a category to NSString to replace all these non-dictionary elements in returned object with NSDictionary friendly textual format, then cast to ios NSDictionary and use standard object access methods ? I'm wondering if this is the right approach or is there a better, more elegant way ? Thank you.

Comment: I use RABL as well to output errors as well, so this seems like a viable solution on the server side. I do not control the iOS code so I won't make a determination there, but will pass it along. Thanks for your input.